# Send emoji with indy delphi7

Tags: delphi, unicode, delphi-7, emoji, indy-9

i want to send emoji with indy 9.00.10 on delphi 7. i use tnt VCL Controls .
i found this url http://apps.timwhitlock.info/emoji/tables/unicode for unicode and bytes code.
how to convert this codes to delphi Constants for Send with indy.

i use this delphi code for send message to telegram bot:

```
procedure TBotThread.SendMessage(ChatID:String; Text : WideString;
parse_mode:string;disable_notification:boolean);
Var
  Stream: TStringStream;
  Params: TIdMultipartFormDataStream;
  //Text : WideString;
  msg : WideString;
  Src : string;
  LHandler: TIdSSLIOHandlerSocket;
begin
  try
    try
      if FShowBotLink then
        Text := Text + LineBreak + FBotUser;
      msg := '/sendmessage';
      Stream := TStringStream.Create('');
      Params := TIdMultipartFormDataStream.Create;
      Params.AddFormField('chat_id',ChatID);
      if parse_mode <> '' then
        Params.AddFormField('parse_mode',parse_mode);
      if disable_notification then
        Params.AddFormField('disable_notification','true')
      else
        Params.AddFormField('disable_notification','false');
      Params.AddFormField('disable_web_page_preview','true');
      Params.AddFormField('text',UTF8Encode(Text));
      LHandler := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocket.Create(nil);
      FidHttpSend.ReadTimeout := 30000;
      FidHttpSend.IOHandler:=LHandler;
      LHandler.SSLOptions.Method := sslvTLSv1;
      LHandler.SSLOptions.Mode := sslmUnassigned;
      FidHttpSend.HandleRedirects := true;
      FidHttpSend.Post(BaseUrl + API + msg, Params, Stream);
    finally
      Params.Free;
      Stream.Free;
    ENd;
 except
   on E: EIdHTTPProtocolException do
   begin
      if E.ReplyErrorCode = 403 then
      begin
       WriteToLog('Bot was blocked by the user');
      end;
   end;
 end;  
end;
```

bytes sample for emojies:

```
AERIAL_TRAMWAY = '\xf0\x9f\x9a\xa1';
AIRPLANE = '\xe2\x9c\x88';
ALARM_CLOCK = '\xe2\x8f\xb0';
ALIEN_MONSTER = '\xf0\x9f\x91\xbe';
```

sorry for bad english!!!

Comment: Indy 9 does not support Unicode. You should upgrade to Indy 10. If that is not an option, I'll have to dig through Indy 9's code to provide other options for you. Either way, what URL are you actually posting to? What are its requirements for posting Unicode input?

Comment: thanks remy for your comment. i change this line to send phone emoji. Params.AddFormField('text',UTF8Encode(Text + LineBreak + #$0000260E )); this works for me but this code not work: #$1F601 for "GRINNING FACE WITH SMILING EYES" emoji. i posting to telegram bot API : https://api.telegram.org/bot. does emoji is unicode? . sorry for bad english.

Comment: how to convert emoji code example U+1F601 and use in delphi?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Telegram Bot API](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api) supports several forms of input:

> We support `GET` and `POST` HTTP methods. We support four ways of passing parameters in Bot API requests:
>
> - URL query string
> - application/x-www-form-urlencoded
> - application/json (except for uploading files)
> - multipart/form-data (use to upload files)

You are using the last option.

Indy 9 does not support Delphi 2009+ or Unicode.  All uses of `string` are assumed to be `AnsiString`, which is the case in Delphi 7.  Any `AnsiString` you add to `TIdMultipartFormDataStream` or `TStrings`, even a UTF-8 encoded one, will be transmitted *as-is* by `TIdHTTP`.  However, there is no option to specify to the server that the string data is actually using UTF-8 as a charset.  But, according to the docs:

> All queries must be made using UTF-8.

So not specifying an explicit charset might not be problem.

If you still have problems with `multipart/form-data`, then consider using `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` (use `TIdHTTP.Post(TStrings)`) or `application/json` (use `TIdHTTP.Post(TStream)`) instead:

```
procedure TBotThread.SendMessage(ChatID: String; Text: WideString; parse_mode: string; disable_notification: boolean);
var
  Params: TStringList;
  LHandler: TIdSSLIOHandlerSocket;
begin
  if FShowBotLink then
    Text := Text + LineBreak + FBotUser;

  Params := TStringList.Create;
  try
    Params.Add('chat_id=' + UTF8Encode(ChatID));
    if parse_mode <> '' then
      Params.Add('parse_mode=' + UTF8Encode(parse_mode));
    if disable_notification then
      Params.Add('disable_notification=true')
    else
      Params.Add('disable_notification=false');
    Params.Add('disable_web_page_preview=true');
    Params.Add('text=' + UTF8Encode(Text));

    LHandler := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocket.Create(nil);
    try
      LHandler.SSLOptions.Method := sslvTLSv1;
      LHandler.SSLOptions.Mode := sslmClient;

      FidHttpSend.HandleRedirects := true;
      FidHttpSend.ReadTimeout := 30000;
      FidHttpSend.IOHandler := LHandler;
      try
        try
          FidHttpSend.Post(BaseUrl + API + '/sendmessage', Params, TStream(nil));
        except
          on E: EIdHTTPProtocolException do
          begin
            if E.ReplyErrorCode = 403 then
            begin
              WriteToLog('Bot was blocked by the user');
            end;
          end;
        end;  
      finally
        FidHttpSend.IOHandler := nil;
      end;
    finally
      LHandler.Free;
    end;
  finally
    Params.Free;
  end;
end;
```

```
procedure TBotThread.SendMessage(ChatID: String; Text: WideString; parse_mode: string; disable_notification: boolean);
var
  Params: TStringStream;
  LHandler: TIdSSLIOHandlerSocket;

  function JsonEncode(const wStr: WideString): string;
  var
    I: Integer;
    Ch: WideChar;
  begin
    // JSON uses UTF-16 text, so no need to encode to UTF-8...
    Result := '';
    for I := 1 to Length(wStr) do
    begin
      Ch := wStr[i];
      case Ch of
        #8: Result := Result + '\b';
        #9: Result := Result + '\t';
        #10: Result := Result + '\n';
        #12: Result := Result + '\f';
        #13: Result := Result + '\r';
        '"': Result := Result + '\"';
        '\': Result := Result + '\\';
        '/': Result := Result + '\/';
      else
        if (Ord(Ch) >= 32) and (Ord(Ch) <= 126) then
          Result := Result + AnsiChar(Ord(wStr[i]))
        else
          Result := Result + '\u' + IntToHex(Ord(wStr[i]), 4);
      end;
    end;
  end;

begin
  if FShowBotLink then
    Text := Text + LineBreak + FBotUser;

  Params := TStringStream.Create('');
  try
    Params.WriteString('{');
    Params.WriteString('chat_id: "' + JsonEncode(ChatID) + '",');
    if parse_mode <> '' then
      Params.WriteString('parse_mode: "' + JsonEncode(parse_mode) + '",')
    if disable_notification then
      Params.WriteString('disable_notification: True,')
    else
      Params.WriteString('disable_notification: False,');
    Params.WriteString('disable_web_page_preview: True,');
    Params.WriteString('text: "' + JsonEncode(Text) + '"');
    Params.WriteString('}');
    Params.Position := 0;

    LHandler := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocket.Create(nil);
    try
      LHandler.SSLOptions.Method := sslvTLSv1;
      LHandler.SSLOptions.Mode := sslmClient;

      FidHttpSend.HandleRedirects := true;
      FidHttpSend.ReadTimeout := 30000;
      FidHttpSend.IOHandler := LHandler;
      try
        try
          FidHttpSend.Request.ContentType := 'application/json';
          FidHttpSend.Post(BaseUrl + API + '/sendmessage', Params, TStream(nil));
        except
          on E: EIdHTTPProtocolException do
          begin
            if E.ReplyErrorCode = 403 then
            begin
              WriteToLog('Bot was blocked by the user');
            end;
          end;
        end;  
      finally
        FidHttpSend.IOHandler := nil;
      end;
    finally
      LHandler.Free;
    end;
  finally
    Params.Free;
  end;
end;
```

That being said, your function's `Text` parameter is a `WideString`, which uses UTF-16, so you should be able to send any Unicode text, including emojis.  If you are trying to generate text in your code, just make sure you UTF-16 encode any non-ASCII characters correctly.  For example, codepoint `U+1F601 GRINNING FACE WITH SMILING EYES` is wide chars `$D83D $DE01` in UTF-16:

```
var
  Text: WideString;

Text := 'hi ' + #$D83D#$DE01; // 'hi '
SendMessage('@channel', Text, 'Markup', False);
```

Alternatively, you can use HTML in your text messages, so you can encode non-ASCII characters using numerical HTML entities. According to the docs:

> All numerical HTML entities are supported.

Codepoint `U+1F601` is numeric entity `$#128513;` in HTML:

```
var
  Text: WideString;

Text := 'hi $#128513;'; // 'hi '
SendMessage('@channel', Text, 'HTML', False);
```